Rules for self-study questions
Our friends on Stats have a special tag for self-study questions. The tag can be used to indicate the type of question and lays down some rules. The benefit of adding this wiki tag with rules is that it can be made clear to all users what we expect from such questions and how to best answer them and it gives guidance on what we should we do with questions which might be considered too basic.
So my question is: should we add this tag?
Update
I went ahead and added the tag. We will see how it goes.
Update 2
I have added the tag and removed the clause that says: don't apply the tag in an edit to a question that's not yours. I feel that here we get a sufficient amount of questions by people that are not familiar with this stack and wouldn't use the tag when they should. Now, it can be tagged as such by more experienced users.
Furthermore, I have added the tag to 3 questions and closed them as these questions didn't seem to show the minimal amount of effort expected.

In my humble opinion, the answer is yes, it could be useful, provided that the users will read that wiki-tag and the rules it will describe! :)
It remains a nice idea anyway!

Yes, especially given how many people who ask questions here aren't every practitioners of quant finance.  
